# Can you make Visual Studio use tabs instead of spaces for new template files?

Tags: visual-studio

I've modified my copy of Visual Studio to keep tabs (instead of spaces) in all my files via `Tools => Options => Text Editor => All Languages => Tabs`.  However, when I create a new project or file, any boilerplate code that Visual Studio includes is always padded with spaces, not tabs (and in cases like `web.config`, not the specified number of spaces either).

Is there a way to force these all to use tabs automatically when created?

*Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Pro, but I suspect other people would be interested in this for other versions as well.*

Comment: Which templates? Project or item templates? I don't think you can do that without modifying the underlying XML files.

Comment: This drives me crazy too. I can't stand spaces for indentation and MS has royally effed up 99% of codebases by making this nastiness the default. At least there is format document for the 1% of us.

Comment: And 6 years later - it is still reverting back to spaces at random times.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can without modifying the template contents, but if you invoke Format Document (`Edit => Advanced => Format Document` or the keybinding it shows in the menu) after creating the file it should replace them all according to your settings.

Comment: This needs clarification.  Cannot find it off the main VS menu in 2022.

Comment: @rfreytag the menu command hasn't moved in VS2022, but may be hidden if the command state indicates it's not available (which also depends on which context has focus).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the [Productivity Power Tools 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017) with "Fixed Mixed Tabs". As soon as I add some own code with a tab indent and save the file I get a warning about "mixed tabs". I then can replace the spaces with a click on the "Tabify" button.

Not perfect, but pretty close.